# How to remove files previously added with ng add schematic command

Tags: angular

I have implemented custom schematics angular  ng-add in my own library, It allows to install my library in new project and  makes other custom edit to other files.

Now what can I do if I wanted to uninstall my library and I wanted to come back with my changes? Can I create custom schematics that first remove my previous edit and then removes my library?

I try to install with `ng add @angular/material` then uninstall It and I see that the files previously touched are not modified but remain modified

Answer (score 7):

There's no `ng remove` command. Schematics are written by the developers of the package. You can look into the package's schematic declaration to find out what files are modified. As of now there's no way to automatically do this. You can use `npm uninstall package-name` to remove it from the package.json. You need to manually remove the package imports from module, component etc...

There's issue with discussion on this feature: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900

Comment: This make sense

Comment: version 15 and you can't uninstall a package using angular cli very funny

Comment: I see. If we add many package, things can be so complicated in the app folder, that's why something like this is not available yet .